# How can I hang an IKEA Stockholm mirror on a brick wall?

Tags: hanging, mirror

I found tips for hanging the Stockholm mirror from IKEA using the technique here by Ray Li: https://hackerbits.com/life/how-to-hang-an-ikea-mirror-stockholm/

However, I have a brick wall in the lounge where I want to hang it, so how can I adapt those instructions for my situation?

Comment: **Attention flaggers:** not every post with a link is spam. The [help] encourages people to cite their sources; see [ask].

Comment: @NiallC. -- apologies for being a bit trigger-happy, thanks for clearing the situation up :)

Comment: *Not Linked: the blog post 6 months later where the mirror falls down, because the mirror's plastic hanger nubs are rated for 100% downforce, not 500% sideforce...*  That is the trouble with blog/social media posts like this, people want to look glamorous, so they only post their successes, not their failures...

Answer (score 1):

I used a D-ring (holds 7kg) with two holes then used a nut and bolt (m4*12mm) as shown in the blog and also a 12mm screw directly into the wood (I stopped screwing when I heard little creak).
I wasn't able to use a picture hook as it was a brick wall so used 2 of these sturdy plastic wall hooks (14x9mm) with wallplugs and screws (https://www.prowa-produkte.ch/collections/wandhaken/products/wandhaken-art-610?variant=30337743880258). 
The mirror doesn't hang quite flush there's a small 15mm gap at top and 8mm on the side in the middle. But it's almost perfect and looks very good to me[image][image][image]

Comment: Congrats, by using a second screw straight into the wood, you seem to have averted my #1 concern with the blog's design.